# angularjs material failing to animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs material. It works, but it fails to animate. For instance, the sidenav appears instead of transitioning as it does in the demo.

I have loaded angular-animate

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.1/angular-material.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you added it in as a dependency in the module as well?

`angular.module('myModule', ['ngAnimate']);`

Comment: @JimmyRare `angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize", "ngMaterial", "ngAnimate", "ui.codemirror", "ngRoute", "toaster"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular-material js and css were loaded with different versions.